# Make Text Counter Always Stay Visible

Tags: android, counter, android-textinputlayout, textedit, android-textinputedittext

**Issue: Character Counter Runs Off Screen**

I am finding it extremely difficult to have a character counter which does not disappear once the input text scrolls over one screen size.

This is what I have in the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android.support.design="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android.support.design:errorEnabled="true"
    android.support.design:hintEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="@integer/global_comments_size">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/action_global_comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/edit_comments"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:maxLength="@integer/global_comments_size"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[counter visible until scroll leaves the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C5RR.png)

[Counter becomes invisible as the text scroll over the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2DQx.png)

**Probable Options:**

I see following three options as possible solutions.

1. Make a bottom toolbar and add the counter programmatically
2. Make a pop-up show programmatically once the maximum size is reached
3. Somehow configure TextInputLayout in xml or use some other library.

I would prefer option 3. However, am at loss right now and do not find any solution or hint neither in the documentation nor by googling the forums.

---

## Solved

**Solution Found**

After more reading I found out that the question has already been asked on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422744/textinputlayout-edittext-counter-runs-off-screen-in-linearlayout) about counter running off the screen with solution proposals.
However, the solution is not as expected with a simple xml entry but has to be done programmatically

I am posting my solution with source code based on the information collected from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422744/textinputlayout-edittext-counter-runs-off-screen-in-linearlayout) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextInputLayout EditText counter runs off screen in LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422744/textinputlayout-edittext-counter-runs-off-screen-in-linearlayout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by reading through the documentation and stackoverflow.
I am posting a complete example here to make it easier to reproduce the behavior.

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way of simply configuring an xml property which would make the counter stay in visible area of screen.

The solution lies in using the interface class TextWatchers which luckily requires only a few lines of code.

**1)** Create *res/values/strings.xml* file to define the constant for the maximum character size

```
<integer name="max_comment_size">50</integer>
```

**2)** add the following two views in your activity
*i.e. res/layout/activity_main.xml*

I like to have the counter on top. You may want to swap TextView and TextEdit if you prefer having it at the bottom.

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/constraint_textview"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Remaining characters/Maximum characters: --/--" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="@integer/max_comment_size" />
```

Please note that textMultiLine does not limit the number of maximum lines for the EditText field. It only limits the layout size.
With maxLength, you can specify the maximum number of allowed characters.

**3)** Use TextWatcher in the java file to count entered characters and show them in the TextView
*Java file in my example is: java/com/example/mycompany/textcounter/MainActivity.java*

The interface class TextWatcher has three methods which need to be implemented. However, only onTextChange() is of interest to us for this purpose.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private TextView mTextView;
        private EditText mEditText;
        private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {  } //nothing to be done here

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {        
                Integer max_comment = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.max_comment_size);

                mTextView.setText("Remaining characters" + "/Maximum characters: "+ String.valueOf(max_comment-s.length()) +"/" + max_comment);
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { } //nothing to be done here
        };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //Initializing views
            mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.constraint_textview);

           mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);

        }        
    }
```

**Further Notes:**

The solution is based on information provided 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422744/textinputlayout-edittext-counter-runs-off-screen-in-linearlayout) about counter running off screen and 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android) on how to use TextWatcher

See android documentation on [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) and [TextEdit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(android.content.res.ColorStateList)), too.

I have limited the maximum number of input character in my TextEdit field with maxLength.
If you do need to limit the maximum number of lines, see discussion and possible solutions 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672234/android-how-to-make-text-in-an-edittext-exactly-fixed-lines/20120343#20120343) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092961/edittext-maxlines-not-working-user-can-still-input-more-lines-than-set) or use the search on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

**All you have to do is to use alignParent like this**

```
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android.support.design="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/action_global_comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/edit_comments"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="@integer/global_comments_size"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textContainer"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android.support.design:errorEnabled="true"
    android.support.design:hintEnabled="true"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="@integer/global_comments_size"/></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The counter is now visible as the two widgets are place beneath each other. However, the counter seems to be separated from the input in TextInputEditText. It constantly shows 0/100, i.e. does not count.

Comment: Thanks for your post. It actually helped me think about making a new view which lead me to the solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422744/textinputlayout-edittext-counter-runs-off-screen-in-linearlayout) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android)

Comment: I am upvoting your post since it did help me with guidance.